# Never reaching eof using ifstream (cpp)

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am reading text from a text file, but I never reach eof, which results in an 
endless loop.

Here's what I wrote

```
static ifstream inF;
inF.open(file,ifstream::in);
cin.rdbuf(inF.rdbuf());
while (inF.good() && !inF.eof())
{
    addStudent(students);
}
if (inF.is_open())
{
    inF.close();
    inF.clear();
}
```

Every Iteration of the loop I call addStudents, which handles only one line. That works fine for me. Basically I rad lines in the form of D 98 76.5 66 45 (Possibly) 12000
here's the code:

```
static void addStudent(vector<Student*> students)
{
char institution;
unsigned short id;
double gAverage, pGrade, salary;
cin >> institution;

switch (institution)
{
case ALICE:
    cin >> id >> gAverage >> salary;
        students.push_back(new Student(institution,id,gAverage,salary));
        return;
case BOB:
    cin >> id >> gAverage >> salary;
    students.push_back(new Student(institution,id,gAverage,salary));
    return;
case COLIN:
    cin >> id >> gAverage >> pGrade >> salary;
    students.push_back(new                  CollegeStudent(institution,id,gAverage,pGrade,salary));
    return;
case DANNY:
cin >> id >> gAverage >>  pGrade >> salary;
    students.push_back(new CollegeStudent(institution,id,gAverage,pGrade,salary));
    return;
}
}
```

When I get to the end of the file the loop keeps running, and addStudents (which returns void) does nothing. Any Ideas why?
Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code for `addStudent`.

Comment: Would need to also see addStudents - but its likely you are never incrementing the position of the original ifstream (its always at the beginning and will always return true for good() and !eof()

Answer (score 3):

Your file stream may share it's stream buffer with `cin`, but it doesn't share it's flags.  So when you read using cin's `operator>>`, and it the reaches end of the file, `cin` sets it's own eof flag, but it doesn't set the flag in your `ifstream`(how could it? it has no knowledge of it).

This is an awfully silly way to read a file, why are you doing it like that?  Why don't you just pass an `istream` reference into your addStudent function and read from that?

Comment: Well, we were instructed to redirect input to a file, so that's what I did. I can use ifstream.getLine() but then I'm not making use of the redirection right?

Comment: @yotamoo: You can do it like you're doing now, you just need to check for eof against cin, not inF, because the status of inF never changes.

Comment: I think your teacher probably wanted you to directly process cin - so you could redirect output of other operations into it for processing (like making it part of a pipe).  What you've done putting cin into another stream doesn't really make much sense programmatically :/